# Bug on BOOT, Ubuntu ask register new user when one user already configured

Tags: boot, 20.04, bug-reporting

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my DELL INSPIRON.

Everything works fine, but the last 2 times I  booted the PC, Ubuntu shows me a welcome window and let me configure new account, even I have already a user configured.

By now I configured a new user and then deleted it.

Anyone saw this bug?

Enrico

Comment: Seems like classic symptoms of a botched install more than a bug. A properly-installed Ubuntu system has a login screen, not a configure-new-user screen. If it really is a bug, please provide more details.

Comment: Please update with a picture of the Welcome screen. And, do you press any keys before you see the Welcome screen?

Comment: I must correct my previous sentence, after the boot, the gnome interface starts, with the initialization for a new user, but my user (set as administrator from GUI) is set as administrator is already configured. If i finish the process of the initialization of the GNOME interface for the new user and i click log off the message:
Log Out gnome-initial-setup
gnome-initial setup will be logged out automatically in 50 seconds.

If i click Log Out, the grafical  user interface switch off and the system restart.
I hope this is more userful...